# Algolia googleMaps widget not working with instant search

Tags: javascript, algolia

So far, I'm using aloglia's instant search as following:

```
app({
  appId: 'XXXXXXX',
  apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  indexName: 'dev_POST_WEBDEV'
});

function app(opts) {
  var search = instantsearch({
  appId: opts.appId,
  apiKey: opts.apiKey,
  indexName: opts.indexName,
  urlSync: true
});

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '.element',
    placeholder: 'Search for products'
  })
);

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
   container: '#hits',
   hitsPerPage: 16,
  templates: {
   item: getTemplate('hit'),
   empty: getTemplate('no-results')
 },
 transformData: function(hit) {
   hit.stars = [];
   for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
     hit.stars.push(i <= hit.sellerRating);
   }
   return hit;
   }
 })
);

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.googleMaps({
    container: document.querySelector('#randommap')
  })
);
search.start();
}
```

The instant search part works and displays the items correctly, however the map never seems to update as you search. I've checked online examples and seem to be doing more or less the same thing.

Is there specific syntax that is needed to get the google maps widget working? The map loads initially, but it fails to place the pins onto the map as I'm instant searching.

Comment: Hi, this should be working indeed, can you create a jsfiddle so we all check the whole page?

Comment: Heres a bitbucket repo you can clone to view. Tried using jsfiddle but the search features weren't working at all. https://justinzh_1@bitbucket.org/vivekjain1397/cyrcle_web.git

Comment: I could not access the repository. Do you have any error message in console? The fact that the jsfiddle could not work is something to look into first. It would be a lot easier with a jsfiddle to help you.

We need an easy to reproduce way. Try to reproduce the issue and get an error message with the least amount of code/data, this will help a lot. Thanks!